# searchTwitter - search tweet but not handle

Tags: r, twitter

Trying to dabble in doing some basic sentiment analysis using twitteR library and `searchTwitter` function. Say I'm searching for tweets specific to "Samsung". I can retrieve the tweets with the below command:

```
samsung_t = searchTwitter("#samsung", n=1500, lang="en",cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

This I know will return all the tweets containing the hash-tag #samsung. However, if I wanted to search for tweets containing "samsung" in them: I give the same command but without the "#"

```
 samsung_t = searchTwitter("samsung", n=1500, lang="en",cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

This however will return all the tweets containing the term "samsung" in them including the handle. For example: it will return a tweet: "@I_Love_Samsung: I like R programming", which is completely irrelevant to my criteria. If I wanted to do a sentiment analysis on say, "Samsung phones", I'm afraid that data like this can skew the results.

Is there a way I can force searchTwitter to only look in the "Tweet" but not the "Handle"?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You could check out Pablo Barbera's R package for the Twitter Streaming API. http://pablobarbera.com/blog/archives/1.html. Alternatively, you could always just filter out those tweets afterward.

Comment: Hi-thanks for the link. This package looks promising. But didnt get one  thing-so using this, we can only download the tweets after a certain point of time(eg. download all tweets within the last 5 mins) as opposed to downloading all the tweets matching a critera from the begininning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [search API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) and the listing of available [search operators](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577-using-advanced-search#), I don't think the twitter search API offers this specific search capability (which seems kind of strange, frankly). I think your best bet is probably to run your search with the tools available to you and filter out the tweets that don't match your criteria from the results you get back.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Guess I'll just have to filter them out after I "download" them.